# AmCharts turn off Axis by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

Trying to make it so few axis would turn off by default (`onLoad`). I thought about using `AmCharts` events on ready.

But I cant find any documentation for ether an event `toggleOff` or what so. Nor something that `AmCharts` would have via default. The only thing that crossed my mind was, making a custom legend item that would toggle off on, but that's not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show/hide axis results on creation, use `someAxis.hidden = true;`, if you want to hide whole graph use - `showGraph(YourGraph)`, `hideGraph(YourGraph)` there is no need to add event listeners, unless your doing some kind of complex check, then go ahead, but `hidden = true` should do fine in most case scenarios, I am pretty sure you can all ways update it anyways and then validate Data.